# How to convert JavaPairInputDStream into DataSet/DataFrame in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to receive streaming data from **kafka**. In this process I am able to receive and store the streaming data into **JavaPairInputDStream**. Now I need to analyze this data with out storing it into any database.So I want to convert this **JavaPairInputDStream** to **DataSet** or **DataFrame**

What I tried so far is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.AbstractJavaDStreamLike;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;


import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

//Streaming Working Code

public class KafkaToSparkStreaming 
{
    public static  void main(String arr[]) throws InterruptedException
    {


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.app.name", "SparkReceiver"); //The name of application. This will appear in the UI and in log data.
        //conf.set("spark.ui.port", "7077");    //Port for application's dashboard, which shows memory and workload data.
        conf.set("dynamicAllocation.enabled","false");  //Which scales the number of executors registered with this application up and down based on the workload
        //conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost"); //Cassandra Host Adddress/IP
        conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");  //For serializing objects that will be sent over the network or need to be cached in serialized form.
        //conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181"); //Make all kafka data for this cluster appear under a particular path. 
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "testgroup");   //String that uniquely identifies the group of consumer processes to which this consumer belongs
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092"); //Producer can find a one or more Brokers to determine the Leader for each topic.
        kafkaParams.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder"); //Serializer to use when preparing the message for transmission to the Broker.
        kafkaParams.put("request.required.acks", "1");  //Producer to require an acknowledgement from the Broker that the message was received.

        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("ny-2008.csv");

        //Create an input DStream for Receiving data from socket
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, 
                String.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                kafkaParams, topics);

    //System.out.println(directKafkaStream);
        directKafkaStream.print();
}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the complete working code using Spark 2.0.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;


public class KafkaToSparkStreaming {
    public static  void main(String arr[]) throws InterruptedException
    {


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.app.name", "SparkReceiver"); //The name of application. This will appear in the UI and in log data.
        //conf.set("spark.ui.port", "7077");    //Port for application's dashboard, which shows memory and workload data.
        conf.set("dynamicAllocation.enabled","false");  //Which scales the number of executors registered with this application up and down based on the workload
        //conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost"); //Cassandra Host Adddress/IP
        conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");  //For serializing objects that will be sent over the network or need to be cached in serialized form.
        conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181"); //Make all kafka data for this cluster appear under a particular path. 
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "testgroup");   //String that uniquely identifies the group of consumer processes to which this consumer belongs
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092"); //Producer can find a one or more Brokers to determine the Leader for each topic.
        kafkaParams.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder"); //Serializer to use when preparing the message for transmission to the Broker.
        kafkaParams.put("request.required.acks", "1");  //Producer to require an acknowledgement from the Broker that the message was received.

        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("ny-2008.csv");

        //Create an input DStream for Receiving data from socket
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, 
                String.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                kafkaParams, topics);

        //Create JavaDStream<String>
        JavaDStream<String> msgDataStream = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
              return tuple2._2();
            }
          });
        //Create JavaRDD<Row>
        msgDataStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) { 
                  JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
                      @Override
                      public Row call(String msg) {
                        Row row = RowFactory.create(msg);
                        return row;
                      }
                    });
        //Create Schema       
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {DataTypes.createStructField("Message", DataTypes.StringType, true)});
        //Get Spark 2.0 session       
        SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context().getConf());
        Dataset<Row> msgDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
        msgDataFrame.show();
              }
        });

        ssc.start();            
        ssc.awaitTermination();  
    }

}

class JavaSparkSessionSingleton {
      private static transient SparkSession instance = null;
      public static SparkSession getInstance(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(sparkConf)
            .getOrCreate();
        }
        return instance;
      }
    }
```

Comment: dont working this code,and JavaSparkSessionSingleton is compilation error

Comment: I have added complete code. This will work in Spark 2.0. If you want to run it in Spark 1.6.2 then you need to modify JavaSparkSessionSingleton and get SQLContext as given in examples/streaming/JavaSqlNetworkWordCount.java of 1.6.2 version

Comment: thanks man its working,i am struguling 3 days for this code,you are solving only 1 hour,you are very very inteligent man,my mail id is:kumara1223@gmail.com,please touch with me. thank you friend.

Answer (score 4):

Technically `Dstream` is sequence of `RDDs`, you won't convert `Dstream` to `Datframe` instead you will convert each `RDD` to `Dataframe/Dataset` as below(Scala code please convert it in Java for your case):

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  val dataFrame = rdd.map {case (key, value) => Row(key, value)}.toDF()

}
```